# How to generate a GitHub flavoured markdown file using knitr?

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, r-markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I love using **`knitr`** to generate dynamic reports and share them with my co-workers using GitHub. What I usually do is to knit my Rmarkdown script --`knit ('myfile.Rmd')`-- and generate a markdown (`myfile.md`) version that can be directly seen on GitHub. The markdown file on GitHub works much better for me than a HTML file that knitr generates with pandoc.

This workflow usually works flawless except when I want to display a table. At the moment I'm using `kable` inside the R-chunk which works pretty nicely if the end product is an HTML file.

My R-chunk looks like:

````
```{r}
library (knitr)
data (cars)
kable (head (cars))
```
````

When `kable` is called from the console, I get the piped table I want:

```
| speed| dist|
|-----:|----:|
|     4|    2|
|     4|   10|
|     7|    4|
|     7|   22|
```

which **is** nicely displayed by GitHub.

However, what `knit('myfile.Rmd')` generates in `myfile.md` (when `kable` is called from the R-chunk) is a simple table

```
speed   dist
------  -----
    4      2
    4     10
    7      4
    7     22
```

which **is not** nicely displayed by GitHub.

Is there any way to make the tables in my markdown file compatible with the GitHub flavoured markdown?. Maybe there is a `knitr` or `kable()` option I'm not aware of? Or maybe there is an alternative to `kable` that achieves the desired results?

Comment: IMHO this should work without problems, can you please share your `sessionInfo()`? But if you are looking for alternative to `kable`, I'm always happy to promote my [pander package](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#markdown-tables) -- especially with `table.style` [set](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#general-options) to `rmarkdown`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the table format via the `format` argument of `kable()`, e.g.

```
kable(head(mtcars), format = 'markdown')
```

Or if you want to set this option globally, you can

```
options(knitr.table.format = 'markdown')
# then just kable(head(mtcars))
```

Answer (score 4):

Pandoc can output to github flavoured markdown with `-t markdown_github`. Using knitr that would be:

```
library(knitr)
pandoc('input.md', format='markdown_github')
```